# I'm calling a Objective-C framework in swift, but it seems not working

Tags: objective-c, swift, github, frameworks

I'm trying to use a Objective-C framework in my swift project.
https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast

Here is the example code

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          kCRToastTextKey : @"Hello World!",
                          kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                          kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor redColor],
                          kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionLeft),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionRight)
                          };
[CRToastManager showNotificationWithOptions:options
                            completionBlock:^{
                                NSLog(@"Completed");
                            }];
```

My codes look like this, it's not working with some errors

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    var option:Dictionary <NSObject,AnyObject> = 
       [kCRToastTextKey : "Hello World!",
        kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : NSTextAlignment.Center,
        kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : UIColor.whiteColor(),
        kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
        kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : CRToastAnimationType.Gravity,
        kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Left,
        kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Right]

    CRToastManager.showNotificationWithOptions(option, completionBlock: nil)
}
```

But when I just keep the 'ColorKey' , it will be fine

```
CRToastManager.showNotificationWithOptions([kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : UIColor.whiteColor()], completionBlock: nil)
```

Thanks a lot if u can help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a quick try, and the problem is with trying to stick Swift's enum values into the dictionary. If you grab the rawValue off each enum, it works for me:

```
var option: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = [
        kCRToastTextKey: "Hello World",
        kCRToastTextAlignmentKey: NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue,
        kCRToastBackgroundColorKey: UIColor.redColor(),
        kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
        kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey: CRToastAnimationType.Gravity.rawValue,
        kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Left.rawValue,
        kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : CRToastAnimationDirection.Right.rawValue
    ]

    CRToastManager.showNotificationWithOptions(option, completionBlock: nil)
```

Comment: I just have quick try, but it doesn't work for me. No errors, but the project is crushed . Thx anyway.

Answer (score -1):

When using Objective-C framework in swift you need to add bridging header file.

See [this link](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/) about bridging headers